# How Can I disable super key?

Tags: keyboard

I want to disable super key when I press nothing should be happen, But I want to retain one option which is helpful Super + Left. Need help regarding this

Comment: I don't have a super key on my keyboard (and I'm not using the default Ubuntu UI) – what happens when you press the super key, and what happens with super+left?

Comment: Hey there,  I was about to say the same. I also want to disable super key and retain the option of Super + Left which is helpful. https://ameerlaw.com/real-estate-law/

Comment: what is currently happening, and what do you want to happen? Please add this to the question. (And what has the law link to do with this?)

Answer (score 1):

To disable the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, you can go into Gnome Tweaks (if this is not installed, `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`.

Then, go into Keyboard and Mouse,
You can either change it to Right Super, or explore the advanced settings and try to disable it there.

Answer (score 0):

Issue following command in the terminal or in the Alt+F2 run dialog to disable the <kbd>Super</kbd> key when pressed alone:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
```

Following command restores the default behavior:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter overlay-key
```

Comment: While this will work, it would be easier if you went to `gnome-tweaks` and changed it under Keyboard & Mouse

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 sounds like that could be its own answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @Vanadium for your support these commands are helpful to disable the super key.  http://apkeverdown.com/

Comment: Thank you so much for your support @vanadium for your support this really help us to disable the Super key and retain the option of Super+Left option. https://surveyforcustomers.com/www-reviewcaptainds-com-2/